# networkx draw_graphviz with chinese label

Tags: python, networkx, neato, pygraphviz

I have a graph where the node labels are in Chinese. I want to draw it using `draw_graphviz()`, but when saving the image, no Chinese characters will display. They instead show as white blocks.

I just want to know how to set the font.

```
nx.draw_graphviz(G, font_size=6, node_size=80, font_family='serif', font_color='b', alpha=0.1)       
plt.savefig("community__large" + str(i) + ".png")  
plt.close()
```

The above is the code I am using now.

Answer (score 5):

> ...where all Chinese word not display instead with block white.

At first I couldn't replicate the behaviour you describe when using `plt.show()`, but when saving the image, the characters show up as white blocks. On my system (OS X 10.8.2, Python 2.7.3), the font SimHei seems to resolve the issue. From the [matplotlib mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/matplotlib/mailman/message/26407518/) I found that the font Microsoft Yahei could work as well, but I haven't tried.

```python
g = nx.Graph()

g.add_edge('挪威'.decode('utf8'), '瑞典'.decode('utf8'))
nx.draw_graphviz(g, font_family='SimHei', node_size=1000,
    node_color='white')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

This produced the following image:

[image: Graph with Chinese labels]

Note that I got the Chinese characters from Google Translate, so I hope it's not anything offensive.